# MySql: Select query

Tags: php, mysql

That is my mat_likes tables:

```
mat_id| yes| no
  1   | 1  | 0
  1   | 1  | 0
  1   | 1  | 0
  2   | 1  | 0
  3   | 1  | 0
  4   | 1  | 0
  4   | 1  | 0
```

How can I select `mat_id` of those materials, which have the most `yes = 1`. Еxample of subtracting the results:

1. `mat_id = 1`, because have total `yes = 3`
2. `mat_id = 4`, because have total `yes = 2`
3. `mat_id = 3`, because have total `yes = 1`
4. `mat_id = 2`, because have total `yes = 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT mat_id,SUM(yes) yes_sum 
FROM mat_likes 
GROUP BY mat_id 
ORDER BY yes_sum DESC
```

will return a result set with the sum of yes's for each mat_id, with the greatest sums on top!

edit: added mat_id to the field list

Answer (score 0):

Check out this website on finding mode, mean, average and that kind of stuff. http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/calculating-mean-median-and-mode-with-sq

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT mat_id, SUM(yes) yes_sum 
FROM mat_likes 
GROUP BY mat_id 
ORDER BY yes_sum DESC, mat_id DESC
```